# Get a Numeric String and Check if is a Hex or Dec number C#

Tags: c#, regex, hex

I'm developing a simple card reader with an USB Emulator Keyboard  card reader.
I'm receiving a string from the card and I want check if the string is a numeric number or an Hex number. I just want accpet the value of that String if is a Hex number.

Since I'm using C#, I know I can use regex, but the problem is that an hex number can have only numbers too and not letters.

Anyone can help me please?
Thank you

my code:

```
    public string ProcessReadContentNumber(string ReadContentNumber)
    {
        Int64 cNumber;
        var hexStyle = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber;

        //  Check If is HEX
        if (Int64.TryParse(ReadContentNumber, hexStyle, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out cNumber))
        {
            String First3Byte = ReadContentNumber.Substring(0, 6);

            String NextBytes = ReadContentNumber.Substring(6);

            //Convert First 3 Bytes
            Int64 decAgain1 = int.Parse(First3Byte, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

            //Convert Last 4 Bytes
            Int64 decAgain2 = Int64.Parse(NextBytes, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

            String FinalNumber = decAgain1.ToString() + "-" + decAgain2.ToString();

            return FinalNumber;   
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I hope the hex you are getting is like 0x......... ! If so its easy to differentiate!

Comment: If its not, 0x decorated then its simply not possible, is "123" 123 or 291 ?  Hard to believe a device interface would be designed so that this is an issue ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need to use regex for that? Try to parse it:

```
string maybeHex = "fffe";
int number;
var hexStyle = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber;
if( int.TryParse(maybeHex, hexStyle, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out number))
{
    // valid
    Console.WriteLine("Valid hex number: " + number);
}
```

That refuses input like `978787879` even it it was a valid integer.

Comment: I will try it Tim, but since your solution refuses inputs like 938938, probably is what I need. Thank you

Comment: Time Schmelter the problem of that code is aimed to the fact that will accept numbers like: 1111111

Comment: @user3178157: but 1111111  is a valid value for a hex number, it's decimal representation is 17895697. http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter